# how to get max value out of 8 column and respective word linked to it

Tags: r

This is what I have as data in R:

SQR_1 is linked with Freq1
SQR_2 is linked with Freq2.. and so on.

| GUID | SESSION_SKEY | SEQNUM | parent_uid | SQR_01 | SQR_02 | SQR_03 | SQR_04 | SQR_05 | SQR_06 | SQR_07 | SQR_08 | Freq1 | Freq2 | Freq3 | Freq4 | Freq5 | Freq6 | Freq7 | Freq8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 004ce66617739f9705a73dd001dd5ff7 | 3.84E+13 | 56 | 2216028557 | volkite | culverin | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | 3 | 2 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 004ce66617739f9705a73dd001dd5ff7 | 3.84E+13 | 153 | 2216028557 | contemptor | dreadnought | volkite | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | 3 | 2 | 3 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 004ce66617739f9705a73dd001dd5ff7 | 3.84E+13 | 217 | 2216028557 | land | raider | prometheus | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | 9 | 1 | 1 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 004ce66617739f9705a73dd001dd5ff7 | 3.84E+13 | 12 | 2216028557 | contemptor | pattern | volkite | culverin | NA | NA | NA | NA | 3 | 1 | 3 | 2 | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 05f7cdbb17a0a45e3fcb79bfffc8817c | 3.84E+13 | 250 | 1297482930 | fake | london | genius | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | 2 | 2 | 2 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 0827fedf17611f9bede0fab001e6dcad | 3.84E+13 | 62 | 72778457 | teapot | for | one | set | NA | NA | NA | NA | 1 | 26 | 4 | 21 | NA | NA | NA | NA |

This is what I  want as final output ("Max freq" & "SQR_word" as output):

| GUID | SESSION_SKEY | SEQNUM | parent_uid | SQR_01 | SQR_02 | SQR_03 | SQR_04 | SQR_05 | SQR_06 | SQR_07 | SQR_08 | Freq1 | Freq2 | Freq3 | Freq4 | Freq5 | Freq6 | Freq7 | Freq8 | Max freq | SQR_word |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 004ce66617739f9705a73dd001dd5ff7 | 3.84E+13 | 56 | 2216028557 | volkite | culverin | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | 3 | 2 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | 3 | volkite |
| 004ce66617739f9705a73dd001dd5ff7 | 3.84E+13 | 153 | 2216028557 | contemptor | dreadnought | volkite | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | 3 | 2 | 3 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | 3 | contemptor,volkite |
| 004ce66617739f9705a73dd001dd5ff7 | 3.84E+13 | 217 | 2216028557 | land | raider | prometheus | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | 9 | 1 | 1 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | 9 | land |
| 004ce66617739f9705a73dd001dd5ff7 | 3.84E+13 | 12 | 2216028557 | contemptor | pattern | volkite | culverin | NA | NA | NA | NA | 3 | 1 | 3 | 2 | NA | NA | NA | NA | 3 | contemptor,volkite |
| 05f7cdbb17a0a45e3fcb79bfffc8817c | 3.84E+13 | 250 | 1297482930 | fake | london | genius | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | 2 | 2 | 2 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | 2 | fake,london,genius |
| 0827fedf17611f9bede0fab001e6dcad | 3.84E+13 | 62 | 72778457 | teapot | for | one | set | NA | NA | NA | NA | 1 | 26 | 4 | 21 | NA | NA | NA | NA | 26 | for |

Comment: Instead of posting pictures, please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610) ("reprex"), by pasting the output of `dput(your_dataset)`.

Comment: @Greg  could you please help?

Comment: Thank you for putting the data in a nice table!  But please also paste the output from `dput(your_data)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `base R` to do this - get the index of 'Freq' and 'SQR' columns ('i1', 'i2'), then get the `max` of the 'Freq' columns with `pmax` for each row, `replace` the 'SQR' corresponding columns where the value for 'Freq' columns is not max to `NA`, loop over the rows with `apply` (`MARGIN = 1`), remove the `NA` and `paste` the 'SQR' words.  Create two new columns in 'df1'

```
i1 <- startsWith(names(df1), 'Freq')
i2 <- startsWith(names(df1), "SQR")
 
f1 <- function(x) {
        if(all(is.na(x))) {
         NA_character_
        } else paste(na.omit(x), collapse = ",")
}
        
mx <- do.call(pmax, c(df1[i1], na.rm = TRUE))
wrd <- apply(replace(df1[i2], df1[i1] != mx, NA), 1, FUN = f1)
df1[c("MaxFreq", "SQR_word")] <- list(mx, wrd)
```

-output

```
> df1
                              GUID SESSION_SKEY SEQNUM parent_uid     SQR_01      SQR_02     SQR_03   SQR_04 SQR_05 SQR_06 SQR_07 SQR_08 Freq1 Freq2 Freq3 Freq4
1 004ce66617739f9705a73dd001dd5ff7     3.84e+13     56 2216028557    volkite    culverin       <NA>     <NA>     NA     NA     NA     NA     3     2    NA    NA
2 004ce66617739f9705a73dd001dd5ff7     3.84e+13    153 2216028557 contemptor dreadnought    volkite     <NA>     NA     NA     NA     NA     3     2     3    NA
3 004ce66617739f9705a73dd001dd5ff7     3.84e+13    217 2216028557       land      raider prometheus     <NA>     NA     NA     NA     NA     9     1     1    NA
4 004ce66617739f9705a73dd001dd5ff7     3.84e+13     12 2216028557 contemptor     pattern    volkite culverin     NA     NA     NA     NA     3     1     3     2
5 05f7cdbb17a0a45e3fcb79bfffc8817c     3.84e+13    250 1297482930       fake      london     genius     <NA>     NA     NA     NA     NA     2     2     2    NA
6 0827fedf17611f9bede0fab001e6dcad     3.84e+13     62   72778457     teapot         for        one      set     NA     NA     NA     NA     1    26     4    21
  Freq5 Freq6 Freq7 Freq8 MaxFreq           SQR_word
1    NA    NA    NA    NA       3            volkite
2    NA    NA    NA    NA       3 contemptor,volkite
3    NA    NA    NA    NA       9               land
4    NA    NA    NA    NA       3 contemptor,volkite
5    NA    NA    NA    NA       2 fake,london,genius
6    NA    NA    NA    NA      26                for
```

---

Or may use `tidyverse` to create the columns - reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` and do a group by `summarise` to create the columns and then bind the columns with original data

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
   dplyr::select(rn, starts_with("SQR"), starts_with("Freq")) %>% 
   rename_with(~ str_remove(., "_0?")) %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -rn, names_to = c(".value", "grp"),
       names_sep = "(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)", values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
   group_by(rn) %>% 
   summarise(MaxFreq = max(Freq), 
         SQR_word = str_c(SQR[Freq == MaxFreq], collapse=",")) %>% 
   select(-rn) %>%
   bind_cols(df1, .)
```

-output

```
                             GUID SESSION_SKEY SEQNUM parent_uid     SQR_01      SQR_02     SQR_03   SQR_04 SQR_05 SQR_06 SQR_07 SQR_08 Freq1 Freq2 Freq3 Freq4
1 004ce66617739f9705a73dd001dd5ff7     3.84e+13     56 2216028557    volkite    culverin       <NA>     <NA>     NA     NA     NA     NA     3     2    NA    NA
2 004ce66617739f9705a73dd001dd5ff7     3.84e+13    153 2216028557 contemptor dreadnought    volkite     <NA>     NA     NA     NA     NA     3     2     3    NA
3 004ce66617739f9705a73dd001dd5ff7     3.84e+13    217 2216028557       land      raider prometheus     <NA>     NA     NA     NA     NA     9     1     1    NA
4 004ce66617739f9705a73dd001dd5ff7     3.84e+13     12 2216028557 contemptor     pattern    volkite culverin     NA     NA     NA     NA     3     1     3     2
5 05f7cdbb17a0a45e3fcb79bfffc8817c     3.84e+13    250 1297482930       fake      london     genius     <NA>     NA     NA     NA     NA     2     2     2    NA
6 0827fedf17611f9bede0fab001e6dcad     3.84e+13     62   72778457     teapot         for        one      set     NA     NA     NA     NA     1    26     4    21
  Freq5 Freq6 Freq7 Freq8 MaxFreq           SQR_word
1    NA    NA    NA    NA       3            volkite
2    NA    NA    NA    NA       3 contemptor,volkite
3    NA    NA    NA    NA       9               land
4    NA    NA    NA    NA       3 contemptor,volkite
5    NA    NA    NA    NA       2 fake,london,genius
6    NA    NA    NA    NA      26                for
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(GUID = c("004ce66617739f9705a73dd001dd5ff7", "004ce66617739f9705a73dd001dd5ff7", 
"004ce66617739f9705a73dd001dd5ff7", "004ce66617739f9705a73dd001dd5ff7", 
"05f7cdbb17a0a45e3fcb79bfffc8817c", "0827fedf17611f9bede0fab001e6dcad"
), SESSION_SKEY = c(3.84e+13, 3.84e+13, 3.84e+13, 3.84e+13, 3.84e+13, 
3.84e+13), SEQNUM = c(56L, 153L, 217L, 12L, 250L, 62L), parent_uid = c(2216028557, 
2216028557, 2216028557, 2216028557, 1297482930, 72778457), SQR_01 = c("volkite", 
"contemptor", "land", "contemptor", "fake", "teapot"), SQR_02 = c("culverin", 
"dreadnought", "raider", "pattern", "london", "for"), SQR_03 = c(NA, 
"volkite", "prometheus", "volkite", "genius", "one"), SQR_04 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, "culverin", NA, "set"), SQR_05 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), SQR_06 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), SQR_07 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), SQR_08 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Freq1 = c(3L, 
3L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 1L), Freq2 = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 26L), Freq3 = c(NA, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L), Freq4 = c(NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 21L), Freq5 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Freq6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Freq7 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Freq8 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: hi @akrun
I have more than 5000 records. I am getting the below error:

Error: Can't recycle `..1` (size 5000) to match `..2` (size 2966).
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 1 rows [1].

Comment: @rgambhava not sure about the error.   Do you have the updated packages?  I showed a base R solution as well, which doesn't require any packages.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes I have tried that as well. Below is the error I am getting:
> wrd <- apply(replace(df6[i2], df6[i1] != mx, NA), 1, 
+              FUN = function(x) paste(na.omit(x), collapse = ","))
Error in `[.data.table`(df6, i2) : 
  i evaluates to a logical vector length 39 but there are 5000 rows. Recycling of logical i is no longer allowed as it hides more bugs than is worth the rare convenience. Explicitly use rep(...,length=.N) if you really need to recycle.

Comment: > df6[c("MaxFreq", "SQR_word")] <- list(mx, wrd)
Error in `[.data.table`(x, i, which = TRUE) : 
  When i is a data.table (or character vector), the columns to join by must be specified using 'on=' argument (see ?data.table), by keying x (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted, see ?setkey), or by sharing column names between x and i (i.e., a natural join). Keyed joins might have further speed benefits on very large data due to x being sorted in RAM.

Comment: @rgambhava I believe that it is an issue with `na.omit` if there are no non-NA elements.  We can create a logical with `FUN = function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) NA_character_ else paste(na.omit(x), collapse = ","))`

Comment: @rgambhava try the update in the post and see if you have the same issue

Comment: @rgambhava your second issue is that you have a `data.table`.  whereas I used `data.frame` .  Convert to `data.frame` and it should work for the base R i.e. `setDF(df1)`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. 
You made my day. Updated code is working.